# Count number of NULL values per region in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, count, null, reducers

Following a previous [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365586/google-earth-engine-set-null-band-values-as-zero) I now have some code which sets null values in an image collection to zero.

I have used this code on several variables, however, I'd like to know which variables have `NULL` values in, opposed to the value just being `0`.

Is there a way of flagging or highlighting an image collection that has null values in it, and maybe counting them per region? I've tried to set the value of the band to the metadata which I can then filter for, but it doesn't seem to work. My code is below:

```js
var currentSpeedNulls = currentSpeed.map(function(image) {
  var Nulls = image.unmask(-999);
  return image.set("current", Nulls.get("current"))});

var currentSpeedNulls1 = currentSpeedNulls
.filterMetadata("current", "equals", -999);

var currentSpeedNulls_mean = currentSpeedNulls1.mean();

//count nulls per region
 var currentSpeedNulls_region = currentSpeedNulls_mean.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  collection: reefs_500,
  scale: 30});
```

Comment: @Rodrigo E. Principe
Can you please provide an example over a collection, not an image?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reduction is fine, but you gotta adapt the input in order to get what you want. I leave you an example:

```
var i = ee.Image.random()
var scale = 1e5

// mask out some pixels
i = i.updateMask(i.lte(0.5))

// add it reprojected to see a bigger size pixels and
// make a better interpretation
Map.addLayer(i.reproject(i.projection().atScale(scale)), {}, 'masked image')
Map.centerObject(geometry, 6)

// get an image in which the only valid pixels are over the mask
// This is the key of the process, the proper input to count over
var mask = i.mask().not().selfMask()

// Inspect the mask layer
Map.addLayer(mask.reproject(i.projection().atScale(scale)), {}, 'mask pixels')


// use a reducer for counting the masked pixels
var count = mask.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13
  })
  
print(count)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c33fb47153a2399ff65c920fba157bc5

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, so the line var mask = i.mask().not().selfMask(), selects the mask, assigns 0 to non-null values and 1 to null values, then adds the actual value where the value is not zero, is this right? If I've assigned -999, I can apply this to an image collection and this should filter out all anything but values of -999 which I can then count per region?

Comment: yes, you could wrap this into a function to map over a collection. In that case the mask to count over would be `mask = i.eq(-999).selfMask()`. At the end you could add `count` as an image property and then filter the collection according to that property.

Comment: Ah great yes! thank you.